# Record with invalid foreign key stored in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In our product, there is, among others, a table `Condition` which contains a foreign key to table `Rule`.

We have an intermittent issue in our nightly test system where a record with an invalid `RuleId` somehow gets stored in the table `Condition`, i.e. there is no `Rule` record with such an `ID`.

I have checked the FK by inserting a new row into the table `Condition` with another invalid `RuleID` and the foreign key constraint is still being enforced.

The nightly test system is just a NUnit runner that runs an API test suite to test the app' API, nothing fancy. The database was created once without any DDL modification by the web app.

Is there any sequence of actions that can result in such a situation?

Comment: Please consider reading the following articles: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_ and _[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)_. Currently your question doesn't contain enough relevant information to  be answerable and will possibly be closed as [**unclear what you are asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: @hot2use Thing is, I'm lost. Postgresql violates the data integrity contract and I don't know what to do. Google search turned up nothing. I even do not know what information should I provide here.

Comment: Well you could start by providing information on your nightly process. What does it do? Is data modified? Is the test system somehow linked with the production database? Cascade on delete?...

Comment: Is the constraint in the "NOT VALID" state?  If so, it will prevent new violations from being created, but will allow pre-existing violations to remain.

Comment: @jjanes Thank for the head up. I will check tomorrow.

Comment: One way to get there is to disable foreign key checks completely using `set session_replication_role = replica` then FK are not checked, not even when that setting is turned back to the correct value.

Comment: Disabling all triggers on a table could also result in such problems, if I am not mistaken.